# How to replace a JPanel with another while the program is running

Tags: java, swing

The code has a JPanel with an inner JPanel that displays awt drawing. Upon mouseclick the inner JPanel is to be replaced by one of its polymorphic siblings. This code isn't replacing the jPanel.

```
class ContentPanel extends JPanel {
```

```
  private GraphicPanel graphicPanel;

  public ContentPanel(GraphicPanel graphicPanel) {
    this.graphicPanel = graphicPanel;
    add(this.graphicPanel);

  public void setGraphicPanel(GraphicPanel graphicPanel) {
    this.graphicPanel = graphicPanel;
```

//      invalidate();
//      revalidate();
//      repaint();
    }

Setting the graphicPanel to a polymorphic relative doesn't cause any errors, it just isn't painting the new graphicPanel. Using cardLayout is not preferred, there must be a cleaner way. How to proceed?

Comment: The cleaner way is to use a cardlayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in setGraphicPanel, you need to remove the current graphicPanel and add the new one. THEN call revalidate.

something like this:

```
public void setGraphicPanel(GraphicPanel graphicPanel) {
    this.removeAll();
    this.graphicPanel = graphicPanel;
    this.add(graphicPanel);
    this.revalidate();   
}
```

Although CardLayout was designed to do just this thing. Are you sure you don't want to use CardLayout?